# How can I simplify the checking/validating logic in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, error-handling

Here is a sample code of how to write something based on email, session key, and message. 
I use most of the code in error handling, like this:

First, I need check null, then, the length, session, connection with db, lastly, the actually result.... ....It is very ignoring, and the code become very long, how can I simify this? Thank you.

```
if(checkNullExisit($aEmail, $aSessionKey, $aMessage)){    
    //Null params detect
    return;
}  

if(strlen($aEmail) > MAX_EMAIL || strlen($aSessionKey) > MAX_SESSIONKEY ||  strlen($aMessage) > MAX_MESSAGE){
    //Too long
    return;
}      

 if(isSessionValid($aEmail, $aSessionKey)){                   
    if(connectDatabase()){ 

        if(DBManagerSingleton::saveMessage($aEmail, $aSessionKey, $aMessage, NULL)){
            //The ONLY Success Case
            return;
        }else{
            //Can't write in DB
            return;
        }

    }else{
       //DB Cannot Connect   
       return;
    }

 }else{
      //Invalid Session     
      return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shorten your validation and db connections, I think you have two main ways of going about that.

- Procedural: Write functions for this stuff.  E.g. you could just have a valid_email() function.
- OOP: Use OOP to create classes you need, e.g. form validation class

Answer (score 0):

[I feel your pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740278/how-do-i-simplify-form-processing-in-php), validation is a [PITA](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PITA), [using a framework](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules) or stand-alone libraries like [Respect](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) or [Phorms](http://www.artfulcode.net/phorms/) might ease out your pain...